# Unnamed process in Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I have a question ... When I enter the Task Manager, I notice that there are unnamed processes running.

After going into details of this process, I notice that it is the legitimate Windows process `svchost`, but without a name.

But these processes don't stay running all the time... they only do it when I start or restart the computer, and only for a couple of minutes, no more, then they disappear.

In addition, the executable of the process (`svchost`), is located in: `C:\Windows\System32`

Could this be considered normal?

**Note:** I'm running Windows 10 20H2 (Spanish version).

[**(Screenshot)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szxIz.png)

*Sorry, I can't insert embedded images yet*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right click the process and choose *Go To Details* or *Open File Location*.

Comment: Yeah, when I go into details and go to the location of the file of said unnamed process, the file is `svchost`, and the location: `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: The details tab has all the interesting stuff. Turn on the command line column by right clicking the header.

Answer (score 1):

svchost processes are entirely normal. They have been part of Windows for years and are not unique to Windows 10.

Often (not always) there will be a name with the process.

[svchost processes](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/svchost-exe-process-in-windows/)

> Svchost.exe is a process that hosts other Windows services that
> perform various system functions. There can be multiple instances of
> svchost.exe running on your computer, with each instance containing a
> different service.
>
> [Run] ...  task manager. If you just see a small box with a list of
> currently running programs, make sure to click on More details at the
> bottom.
>
> Then click on the Processes tab and scroll past Apps and Background
> Processes until you get to Windows Processes. Keep scrolling down
> until you start seeing Service Host:. There should be quite a few of
> them listed.

You can run a command to get a text list of these services.

> Tasklist Command
>
> On any version of Windows, you can use the command line to generate a
> list of all the svchost.exe processes along with the service that is
> running inside each. To do this, simply open a command prompt by
> clicking on Start and typing in cmd.
>
> At the command prompt, go ahead and copy/paste the following command:
>
> tasklist /svc | find "svchost.exe" This will generate a list of all
> running processes, pass that list to the find command and filter to
> only show the svchost.exe processes. If you want to output this to a
> text file, use the following command:
>
> tasklist /svc | find "svchost.exe" > c:\tasklist.txt Note that in
> order to output to the root of the C drive, you’ll need to open an
> Administrator command prompt (Start, type cmd, right-click on command
> prompt and choose Run as Administrator).

As noted above, scrolling down past the apps in Task Manager, you can see Service Hosts processes with names. It was not always this way. Windows 10 is a big improvement.

You can use the command line also as noted above:  tasklist /svc | find "svchost.exe"

Here is a screen shot of the names shown.

[image]

In summary then, svchost is entirely normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: To summarize @John excellent answer, each service takes up a certain amount of resources.. to get around the need for a separate service for many basic functions (like TCP) ONE process handles multiple threads through a single service (thus saving resources).  As John points out.. it has been this way since at least NT4.. possibly NT3.51.  No need to worry about it.  It only becomes a pain when one of them is misbehaving.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But, that the process doesn't have any name or title is normal?

Comment: It may be normal - it depends on the operating system used. With Windows 10, you can scroll down past the apps in the Process tab and see associated names. In my Windows 7 machine, these associated names are not show. Still, if they are not there for you it may be normal. I posted a screen shot to help you.

Comment: It may be the version you are using and also try the command to show the command  text.

Comment: I have windows 10, and I have done exactly what you mention, I even left a screenshot in this post, to show how these unnamed svchost processes appear. But the fact is that it makes me curious why a name or title is not displayed. And as I mentioned, after going to details and the location of the process, it redirects me to: `C:\Windows\System32`. So.. It's normal?

Comment: What you seeing is normal so far as I know.

Comment: If I do what you do here (fter going to details and the location of the process, it redirects me to: C:\Windows\System32.) I get the same thing here.